# How can I make it so a gif image replays once every time the page refreshes in Wordpress?

Tags: animation, refresh, gif

My gif image playsy one time when I open my Wordpress page and it will replay sometimes when I press refresh but usually it just plays upon loading, the first time. Is there some code I need to make it replay every time I refresh the page?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Whats wrong with my question?